VS Code Python - Inline suggestions not working if bracket (parenthesis, curly bracket, etc) not closed
The issue I'm having is when I start the name of a variable "inside" an unclosed parenthesis or bracket, VS Code will not show any suggestions.
However, if the parenthesis is closed prior to typing the variable name, the suggestions work fine.  If I can avoid it, I'd rather not have autocomplete bracket closing set to True nor use the TabOut extension.  First screenshot shows that suggestions work inside closed parenthesis/brackets and second screenshot shows it no longer works if bracket isn't closed.


I've looked through many of the settings in VS Code and couldn't find anything that pertains to this.

Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Hello, in general, entering parentheses will automatically turn off parentheses. Why don't you need to close the parentheses, is there a different need? The autocomplete code feature is usually done with a complete structure.  If it's in unclosed parentheses, maybe vscode thinks it's incomplete and pauses.

@ toyota Supra - Screenshots are used here to show that the autosuggestion functionality isn't working.

Hello, this could be the bug, I've raised the issue on GitHub. I think can get a reply soon.

@Jeanneli - Thank you so much for doing that!  I'll follow that bug to see if gets resolved.
